# How to select continuous rows in R data frame based on conditions?

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a dataframe df and it has date ,group and gap days column. I want to select for a group all rows where gap days is continuously 1 from latest date (max date) . If gap days is not equal to 1 , then we ignore rows till the point where gap days is not equal to 1 . For reproducible purpose I have created current df and expected df...

```
df<-data.frame(Date=c("2018-10-15","2018-10-16","2018-10-17",
                  "2018-10-14","2018-10-15","2018-10-16","2018-10-18","2018-10-19",
                  "2018-10-18","2018-10-21","2018-10-23","2018-10-24","2018-10-27","2018-10-28"),Group=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c"),Gap_Days=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,3,1,1))


df_expected<-data.frame(Date=c("2018-10-15","2018-10-16","2018-10-17","2018-10-18","2018-10-19","2018-10-27","2018-10-28"),Group=c("a","a","a", "b","b","c","c"),Gap_Days=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: `df[rev(cumall(rev(df$Gap_Days == 1))),]`

Comment: Thanks for the comment , though it does not meet my requirement ...If I apply above code in group by condition....then it only shows those groups where everything was 1 ....If there is only single entry , it does not show that

Comment: It matches your expected output perfectly ... given the test data you provided. If you have further conditions, I suggest you update your test data to capture those conditions.

Comment: thanks .... i  would update my question

Comment: This is where "unit-testing" becomes valuable: find a bug, write a test to highlight that bug, then fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between my first comment and what works now is the introduction of grouping to the question.

Base R:

```
do.call("rbind", by(df, df$Group, FUN=function(d) d[rev(cumall(rev(d$Gap_Days == 1))),]))
#            Date Group Gap_Days
# a.1  2018-10-15     a        1
# a.2  2018-10-16     a        1
# a.3  2018-10-17     a        1
# b.7  2018-10-18     b        1
# b.8  2018-10-19     b        1
# c.13 2018-10-27     c        1
# c.14 2018-10-28     c        1
```

Tidyverse:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(rev(cumall(rev(Gap_Days == 1)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   Date       Group Gap_Days
#   <fct>      <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 2018-10-15 a            1
# 2 2018-10-16 a            1
# 3 2018-10-17 a            1
# 4 2018-10-18 b            1
# 5 2018-10-19 b            1
# 6 2018-10-27 c            1
# 7 2018-10-28 c            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(Gap_Days), 
   ind = any(Date == max(.data$Date))) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   filter(grp == max(grp) & ind) %>% 
   select(-ind, -grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Date       Gap_Days
#  <date>        <dbl>
#1 2018-10-19        1
#2 2018-10-20        1
#3 2018-10-21        1
```

---

If the 'Date' column is already ordered, then we just need to check the 1s in 'Gap_Days

```
i1 <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$Gap_Days == 1), 
           values[lengths < max(lengths) & values] <- FALSE))
df[i1,, drop = FALSE]
```